# Allocation tracker disabled

Tags: android, android-emulator

For some reason the allocation tracker is disabled in my ddms.. i can see the logcat.. also i can see the proccess, but for some weird reason the proccess are shown as '?' in their name.

what could be the reason?
Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, just need to restart the emulator!

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are also running Eclipse and the DDMS cannot attach the debugger. If that is the case, you should also see Logcat entries to that effect, something like 'Second instance of debugger ignored'.

Just shut down Eclipse in that case and restart DDMS. All of the running processes will be visible and the Start Tracking button in the Allocation Tracker should be enabled.